# How to find a minimal sum of numbers associated with tuples of points so the points don't repeat?

Tags: algorithm

I have a structure of data that's presented like this:

```
List<Tuple<Tuple<Node, Node>, int>>
```

Node is just a point with x and y coordinates (integers). A Tuple is the C# Tuple so a pair of values. An int represents the minimal number of movements from source Node to destination Node. So to summarize, it's a List of pairs where first element is the pair consisted of Source and Destination and the second element is the minimal distance between them.

Right now Nodes in the list are repeating, because it contains all possible combinations, for example:

```
Sources:
0,0
1,1
Destinations:
2,2
3,3
List with distances:
((0,0 to 2,2) -> DISTANCE)
((0,0 to 3,3) -> DISTANCE)
((1,1 to 2,2) -> DISTANCE)
((1,1 to 3,3) -> DISTANCE)
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to calculate the minimal movements needed to move some things from all sources to available destinations. So in this case it would be sum of 2 distances, chosen in a way that it is minimal possible solution (sources nor distances can not repeat).

I've tried the simplest solution in which I just ordered my list by distances (from lowest to highest) and then I moved N elements to a result list in a way that sources nor destinations didn't repeat. But of course it's not that simple, because there are cases where it's better not to take a minimal distance to some Node because taking higher one may result in getting lower final result.

I hope that my description of the problem is understandable. I don't need an actual code, some help with getting an idea for an algorithm would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like the [assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem) - "finding a maximum weight matching (or minimum weight perfect matching) in a weighted bipartite graph" (from Wikipedia). I believe a classic solution for this is the [Hungarian algorithm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm).

Comment: That's probably it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

While question description is rather vague, it seems that you need to determine the shortest paths between graph vertices. There are [some algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem) for different kinds of this problem.

For limited number of source vertices it is worth to apply [Dijkstra algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm) that searches shortest paths from given vertex to all others in `O(V^2)` time, so for K sources - `O(K*V^2)`

If number of sources is comparable with overall vertex count, you can use [Floyd-Warshall algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) giving distances between all pairs of vertices in `O(V^3)`

Comment: Actually, I already have shortest paths calculated from each source to all possible destinations. Maybe I can simplify my question: I have N sources and N destinations. I need to find smallest possible number of steps to move all items from its source to any of the destinations (so all destinations are occupied at the end). In the list that I'm describing in the original question I already have the distances for all possibilities, but now I need to sum them in a way that I would get smallest result. So, basically, to choose which items should I move to which destinations to get shortest path.

Comment: Perhaps it is worth to show simple example  to make your question more clear (editing question)